# How to pass info to the constructor from a text file?

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

Suppose there're two classes: `Exam` and `MainExam` (contains a `main` method). class Exam has a constructor

```
public Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID)
```

The class `MainExam` reads data from a tex tfile. For example, the data can be:

```
John Douglas 57
```

How can one pass data to the constructor from a textfile?

Comment: Same way you'd pass data to the constructor from anything else.

Comment: How about as a stream or just the filename/path ?

Comment: How do put data into the object?

Comment: @jordan you should focus your question: your problem is "how to read a file in Java" ? or "How to pass information to a constructor in Java" ?

Comment: @alfasin, how to pass information to a constructor.

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that reads the file (just in case you don't actually have it)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\somefolder\\filename.txt");
String data = scanner.nextLine();
```

Now, assuming your file lines are in the following format:

```
<FirstName> <LastName> <id>
```

without any whitespace in each element, you can use the regex `" "` to `String#split` your `data`

```
String[] arguments = data.split(" ");
```

and then pass them into the constructor (String, String, int)

```
String fn = data[0];
String ln = data[1];
int id = Integer.parse(data[2]);
new Exam(fn, ln, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following snippet to store the contents of your text file in a string object:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //  System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The contents of the file are in sCurrentLine object now. Using StringTokenizer you may separate the firstname, lastname and ID using space as delimiter. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringTokenizer` to break the data into parts that were read by `MainExam`.

```
String str; //data read by MainExam, like: John Douglas 57
String[] values = new String[3]; // size acording to your example 
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
int i=0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    values[i++] = st.nextToekn();
}
```

Now you have the data separated in the array `values`.

Comment: Thanks for the try but StringTokenizer is not allowed for my project

Comment: That means you aren't even allowed to tokenize the String manually?